# How do disable only dates from previeous month

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, momentjs, fullcalendar-3

I have a simple section in which I am showing a calendar for my users using full calendar API, I want to disable only the dates from the previous month.

JSFIDDLE [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5dfe2ypu/1/)

The expected result

[image]

Here is what I have tried so far using full calendar documentation
HTML

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

JS

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
             selectable: true,
                  selectAllow: function(selectInfo) {
                      console.log(selectInfo);
                    return moment().diff(selectInfo.start) <= 0
                  },  
    // set source and define start and end params
    events: [
        {
            id: "1",
            title: "First event",
            start: "20120-03-26 13:00:00",
            end: "2020-03-26 15:00:00",
            className: 'available'
        },
        {
            id: "2",
            title: "Second event",
            start: "2020-03-29 18:00:00",
            end: "2020-03-29 20:00:00",

        }
    ],

});
```

> NOTE: am using full calendar v4

Unfortunately, my solution disable all past dates but I just want only dates from past month should be disabled

What do I need to do to achieve what I want?

Comment: can you add a fiddle to demonstrate your code so far?

Comment: @RachelGallen added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily use momentJS to find the start of the current month, and compare the selected date to that instead.

```
selectAllow: function(selectInfo) {
  var ms = moment().startOf("month");
  return ms.isSameOrBefore(selectInfo.start);
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/yLNRWwZ

See https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/ for more info.

Comment: it's working I will accept your answer, so is it possible to use this method in react?

Comment: I don't know anything about react, but I don't see why not. As long as momentJS is loaded it should work.

Comment: your method works only with old version eg <v3 , not working with version 4 though, there is not such a thing a viewrender there is dateRender etc, alot is changed in version 4

Comment: @user9964622 The original code is using fullCalendar 3, so I answered for fullCalendar 3. What would be the point of giving an answer for a different version? P.S. I haven't used viewRender, that was the other answer (which was incorrect).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add schedules on days less than current date, then you can code it like this :

```
selectable: true,
selectAllow: function(selectInfo) {
  var ms = moment(new Date()).subtract(1, 'day');
  return ms.isSameOrBefore(selectInfo.start);
},
```